# Are two-decimal Ruby Floats guaranteed accurate if you turn them into strings and back again?

Tags: ruby, floating-point

I'm trying to convince the person behind a Ruby lib dealing with money to use BigDecimal, not Float.

This library explicitly only supports two decimals of precision. It takes a float input (e.g. `12.34`), turns it into a string (`12.34.to_s  # => "12.34"`) and sends it to an API. It then gets a string amount back (`"56.78"`) that it turns into a float (`"56.78".to_f  # => 56.78`).

I can easily reproduce Float rounding issues doing math on two-decimal floats (e.g. `139.25 + 74.79  # => 214.04000000000002`).

But assume you don't do math. You only turn a two-decimal number represented as a Float into a string and back again. Is Ruby's Float then guaranteed to be reliable, or can you think of any case where it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily exceed floating point precision for larger numbers:

```
"100000000000000.01".to_f #=> 100000000000000.02
```

Comment: Also calculations wouldn't be as expected: `(1.2 - 1.0) == 0.2
 => false` where as: `(BigDecimal.new("1.2") - BigDecimal("1.0")) == BigDecimal("0.2") => true`.

Comment: @Stefan To slightly tweak my original question: if I don't do calculations, but only switch between Float and String formats,  are two-decimal Floats guaranteed to be reliable within some span of values? If the top of that span has something like 13 or 14 zeroes (like your example number), then it seems like all reasonable currency amounts for all currencies would fall within the safe span.

Comment: @User089247 Thank you. Yes, I was aware of the problem with calculations (and tried to clarify that in the question), but wanted to know if you're guaranteed safe if you don't do calculations.